# JQuery Select option works only four times in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is converter from select element to radio elements, the converter make radio buttons from select options. The select options changed on radio change.
The problem is in browser Firefox, after 4 times changing radio selected, the select option does not changed.
But more strangely, the select option changed in Inspect Element (Q) Ctrl+Shift+c.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.selectToRadio = function(){
   var $self = $(this);
   $self.each(function(i, select){
    var $select = $(select);
    var $ul_ = $('<ul class="video_chat_variable" />');
    $select.find('option').each(function(j, option)
    {
     var $option = $(option);
     var vname = $option.text();
     var $radio = $('<input type="radio" />');
     $radio.attr('name', $select.attr('name')).attr('value', $option.val()).attr('id', $option.val());
     if ($option.attr('selected')) $radio.attr('checked', 'checked');
     var $li_ = $('<li />');
     $li_.append($radio);
     $li_.append($("<label />").attr('for', $option.val()).html(vname));
     $ul_.append($li_);
    });
    $select.before($ul_);
   });

   (function(){
    $('.video_chat_variable').on('change', function() {
     var value = $('input[name=attribute_pa_video_chat]:checked').val();
     //$($self).find('option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
     $self.find('option').each(function(i, select_)
     {
      $(select_).removeAttr('selected');
     });
     $($self).find('option[value=' + value + ']').attr("selected",true).parent().trigger('change');
     
    });
   })(jQuery);
   
   //$(this).hide();
   return $(this);
  }
 })(jQuery);
 $('#pa_video_chat').selectToRadio();
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="pa_video_chat" class="" name="attribute_pa_video_chat" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_video_chat">
 <option selected="selected" class="attached enabled" value="webrtc_chat">WebRTC</option>
 <option class="attached enabled" value="skype_chat">Skype</option>
 <option class="attached enabled" value="facebook_chat">Facebook</option>
 <option class="attached enabled" value="google_chat">Google Hangouts</option>
</select>
```

Comment: do you get any developer tools console errors or messages

Comment: it's not "after 4 times" ... load the page, click skype, click webrtc - now skype wont work - there's a major logic problem in your code

Comment: @Jaromanda X, only TypeError: can't access dead object
view-source:resource://skype_ff_extension-at-jetpack/skype_ff_extension/data/jquery-2.1.0.min.js

Which logic problem?

Comment: @JaromandaX  I verified it works in IE and doesn't work in FireFox.

Comment: Works fine in Chrome, IE, but doesn't in Firefox.

Comment: In one of your comments you mention `jqu‌​ery-2.1.0.min.js` but your code shows `1.11.1/jquery.min.js`.    Can you try using just one version of jQuery?

Comment: @steve-wellens, I tried, the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, after some research :-p found the old answer..

use `prop` instead of `attr` while selection and unselection on your `video_chat_variable` change event ... and now works fine :)

```
$('.video_chat_variable').on('change', function() {
                var value = $('input[name=attribute_pa_video_chat]:checked').val();
                //$($self).find('option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
                $self.find('option').each(function(i, select_)
                {
                    $(select_).prop('selected',false); // changed from $(select_).removeAttr('selected');
                });
                $($self).find('option[value=' + value + ']').prop("selected",true).parent().trigger('change'); // changed from  attr() to prop()                    
            });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, probably the attr() making targeted changes and prop() comprehensive.